# MS Graph API Client UpdateAsync() method gives an error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I attempt to update an object (in this particular case a user) using UpdateAsync(), I get the error:

```
    Message "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target."
```

But Intellisense for the method says it updates the specified User using PATCH, which seems right. Has anyone else experienced this error?

```
await _graphServiceClient.Users[u.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(user)
```

Is anyone aware of another syntax to achieve the same thing? I'm not married to this code ;)

[image]

Comment: It works fine in my side, may I know what properties of user do you want to update ? Could you please share the code of `var user = new User{}` ?

Comment: User user = new User
                {
                    DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
                    GivenName = u.GivenName == null ? "" : u.GivenName,
                    Id = u.Id,
                    JobTitle = u.JobTitle,
                    Mail = u.Mail == null ? "" : u.Mail,
                    MobilePhone = u.MobilePhone,
                    Surname = u.Surname == null ? "" : u.Surname
                };

Comment: Is the thought that the error message is misleading and there are a minimum number of properties you have to send?

Comment: I test with update same properties with yours in my code, it still works fine.

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of all of your code and you can cover the sensitive information in screenshot.

Comment: Pretty simple code. What scopes are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232064/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-cef).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarize the chat records, test with update one property of user in code and found the problem was caused by one of the property(`Id`) is null. It will show error message when the property `Id` is null.

So just add a line of code to avoid null `Id` be inserted during update operation.

Comment: Thanks for being real helpful to a stranger on the internet! Super rare!

Comment: Hey I got another one for you if you are game:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67479091/how-to-update-ms-graph-client-service-principal-approleassignments

Comment: Hi @Cef Could you please create a post with `[azure-active-directory]` tag because your current post is out of my service scope.